# Why can't I create a view with a visual interface?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

When the narrator in the video I watched on the Internet creates a view, he adds tables to the view with a visual interface as in the 1st picture, and sets the relations between the tables. But when I create a view, a code screen greets me and I need to create a view with code. Why can't I create a view with the visual interface? Standalone component etc that I need to install in visual studio. is there? (Note: He's VS version: 2012 , My VS version: 2019)

[image]

When i create a view

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visual interface I'm looking for is also available in SSMS. I use SSMS to use visual interface. my problem is solved.